# unable to login to facebook using asmack on Android

Tags: android, facebook, nullpointerexception, xmpp, asmack

I´m try to connect to facebook using asmack and android. I can connect but not login. when i try to do that i got nullpointerexception on `super.authenticate();` how can i fix this problem, some examples please

Log:

```
 D/tag: connection succeeded
    W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
    W/System.err:   at org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLMechanism.authenticate(SASLMechanism.java:116)
    W/System.err:   at CustomSASLDigestMD5Mechanism.authenticate(CustomSASLDigestMD5Mechanism.java:36)
    W/System.err:   at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:319)
    W/System.err:   at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:204)
    W/System.err:   at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection.login(Connection.java:357)
    W/System.err:   at se.hig.MainActivity.login(MainActivity.java:69)
    W/System.err:   at se.hig.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
    W/System.err:   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    W/System.err:   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
    W/System.err:   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
    W/System.err:   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
    W/System.err:   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
    W/System.err:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-18 10:55:33.384: W/System.err(255):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    07-18 10:55:33.384: W/System.err(255):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
    07-18 10:55:33.393: W/System.err(255):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    W/System.err:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    W/System.err:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    07-18 10:55:33.393: W/System.err(255):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    W/System.err:   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    D/tag: login fails exeption : 
    D/tag:  service-unavailable(503)
```

CustomSASLDigestMD5Mechanism:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.harmony.javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import org.apache.harmony.javax.security.sasl.Sasl;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLMechanism;


public class CustomSASLDigestMD5Mechanism extends SASLMechanism
{

    public CustomSASLDigestMD5Mechanism(SASLAuthentication saslAuthentication)
    {
        super(saslAuthentication);
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticate(String username, String host, String password)

    throws IOException, XMPPException
    {
        this.authenticationId = username;

        this.password = password;
        this.hostname = host;

        String[] mechanisms = { getName() };
        Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
        sc = Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, null, "xmpp", host, props, this);    

        super.authenticate();

    }

    @Override
    public void authenticate(String username, String host, CallbackHandler cbh)

    throws IOException, XMPPException
    {
        String[] mechanisms = { getName() };

        Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();

        sc = Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, null, "xmpp", host, props, cbh);

        super.authenticate();

    }

    protected String getName()
    {

        return "DIGEST-MD5";

    }

}
```

MainActivity:

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private XMPPConnection connection;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        connect();

        login("username", "password");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public String connect()
    {

        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com", 5222);

        SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism("DIGEST-MD5", CustomSASLDigestMD5Mechanism.class);

        config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
        config.setTruststorePath("/system/etc/security/cacerts.bks");
        config.setTruststoreType("bks");
        config.setDebuggerEnabled(false);

        connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
        try
        {
            connection.connect();
            Log.d("tag", "connection succeeded");
        } catch (XMPPException e)
        {
            Log.d("tag", "connection fails exeption : \n " + e);
        }

        // fbml = new FBMessageListener(connection);

        return connection.getConnectionID();

    }

    public boolean login(String userName, String password)
    {

        if ((connection != null) && (connection.isConnected()))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.login(userName, password);
            } catch (XMPPException e)
            {
                Log.d("tag", "login fails exeption : \n " + e);
            }

            return true;

        }

        return false;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not use the standard authentication method.

See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

Comment: It says that DIGEST-MD5 shall work, and i can get the code work in java with the smack library. please provide some example so i can better understand

Answer (score 0):

First of all Edit your SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism class . Copy and paste this code .

```
package com.facebook.android;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.harmony.javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import org.apache.harmony.javax.security.sasl.Sasl;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLMechanism;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.Base64;

import android.util.Log;

public class SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism extends SASLMechanism {

    private static final String NAME              = "X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM";

    private String              apiKey            = "";
    private String              accessToken        = "";

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism(SASLAuthentication saslAuthentication) {
        super(saslAuthentication);
    }

    @Override
    protected void authenticate() throws IOException, XMPPException {
        getSASLAuthentication().send(new AuthMechanism(NAME, ""));
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticate(String apiKey, String host, String accessToken) throws IOException, XMPPException {
        if (apiKey == null || accessToken == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid parameters");
        }

        this.apiKey = apiKey;
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
        this.hostname = host;

        String[] mechanisms = { "DIGEST-MD5" };
        Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
        this.sc = Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, null, "xmpp", host, props, this);
        authenticate();
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticate(String username, String host, CallbackHandler cbh) throws IOException, XMPPException {
        String[] mechanisms = { "DIGEST-MD5" };
        Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
        this.sc = Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, null, "xmpp", host, props, cbh);
        authenticate();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getName() {
        return NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void challengeReceived(String challenge) throws IOException {
        byte[] response = null;

        if (challenge != null) {
            String decodedChallenge = new String(Base64.decode(challenge));
            Map<String, String> parameters = getQueryMap(decodedChallenge);

            String version = "1.0";
            String nonce = parameters.get("nonce");
            String method = parameters.get("method");

            String composedResponse =
                "method=" + URLEncoder.encode(method, "utf-8") +
                        "&nonce=" + URLEncoder.encode(nonce, "utf-8") +
                        "&access_token=" + URLEncoder.encode(accessToken, "utf-8") +
                        "&api_key=" + URLEncoder.encode(apiKey, "utf-8") +
                        "&call_id=0" +
                        "&v=" + URLEncoder.encode(version, "utf-8");
            response = composedResponse.getBytes();
        }

        String authenticationText = "";

        if (response != null) {
            authenticationText = Base64.encodeBytes(response);
        }

        // Send the authentication to the server
        getSASLAuthentication().send(new Response(authenticationText));
    }

    private Map<String, String> getQueryMap(String query) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String[] params = query.split("\\&");

        for (String param : params) {
            String[] fields = param.split("=", 2);
            map.put(fields[0], (fields.length > 1 ? fields[1] : null));
        }

        return map;
    }
}
```

and then use this method to login to face book chat

```
private void testLogin(){
        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com", 5222);
        config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
        config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.enabled);
        xmpp = new XMPPConnection(config);
        SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM",SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism.class);
        SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM", 0);
        Log.i("XMPPClient",
                "Access token to " + mFacebook.getAccessToken());
        Log.i("XMPPClient",
                "Access token to " + mFacebook.getAppId());
        Log.i("XMPPClient",
                "Access token to " + mFacebook.getAccessToken());
        try {
            xmpp.connect();
            Log.i("XMPPClient",
                    "Connected to " + xmpp.getHost());

        } catch (XMPPException e1) {
            Log.i("XMPPClient",
                    "Unable to " + xmpp.getHost());

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            xmpp.login(PreferenceConnector.APP_ID, mFacebook.getAccessToken());


        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }
```